# Subtract two values from populated fields

Tags: javascript

I have a table with some input fields a person will be filling in. It's for an application. I have a total for each set of tables. Right now those are summing up the totals from the fields into a total box for each table. I need an additional field to subtract those two fields to give me one broad total. For some reason I am getting no console errors or total outputted.

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('qty');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total_Assets').value = tot;
}

function findTotal2() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('qty2');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total_liabilities').value = tot;
}

function fnCalculate() {
  //Get the texts from both textboxes
  var txt1 = document.getElementById("total_Assets").value;
  var txt2 = document.getElementById("total_liabilities").value;
  //Substract that
  var res = parseInt(txt1) - parseInt(txt2);
  //Set the value to your div
  document.getElementById("net_worth").innerHtml = res;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-9hbo"><br></th>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">Amount ($)<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Other Assets<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty" onblur="findTotal()" id="other_assets" type="text" name="other_assets" value="[[+fi.other_assets]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty" onblur="findTotal()" id="other_assets_2" type="text" name="other_assets_2" value="[[+fi.other_assets_2]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">(A) TOTAL ASSETS<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input onblur="fnCalculate()" class="totals" id="total_Assets" type="text" name="total_Assets" value="[[+fi.total_Assets]]" readonly /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">(C) NET WORTH (A MINUS B)<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input id="net_worth" type="text" name="net_worth" value="[[+fi.net_worth]]" readonly/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-9hbo"><br></th>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">Amount ($)<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Bank Loans<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty2" onblur="findTotal2()" id="bank_loans" type="text" name="bank_loans" value="[[+fi.bank_loans]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Mortgages and Real Estate<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty2" onblur="findTotal2()" id="mortgages" type="text" name="mortgages" value="[[+fi.mortgages]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">(B) TOTAL LIABILITIES<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input onblur="fnCalculate()" class="totals" id="total_liabilities" type="text" name="total_liabilities" value="[[+fi.total_liabilities]]" readonly /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: removed jQuery tag as there's no jQuery here

Comment: should be `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`. Why you randomly decided to try and set the value of this textbox using a different property (one which doesn't apply to input elements) than all your other textboxes, I don't know. Was it previously a div (or something) in an earlier version, perhaps? Voted to close as just a typo.

Comment: Yes it was a tutorial of sorts I used. I manipulated it to work for my. I changed the .innerHTML to .value but its still not outputting the total

Comment: @BrandonRob0422 You should go again in every input to get and lose the focus to be sure you  to trigger all the calculations. You should calculate everything (when it is possible) each time you leave a text entry or maybe you could create a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed two issues:

1. I have replaced the `.innerHtml` by the `.value` property
2. I call all the calculations each time an entry loses its focus. I think the calculations weren't correctly triggered

In addition to that, I replaced the use of the `value` attribute by `placeholder` to display the field name. That way you don't have to remove the text before entering anything.

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('qty');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total_Assets').value = tot;
}

function findTotal2() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('qty2');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total_liabilities').value = tot;
}

function fnCalculate() {
  findTotal();
  findTotal2();
  //Get the texts from both textboxes
  var txt1 = document.getElementById("total_Assets").value;
  var txt2 = document.getElementById("total_liabilities").value;
  //Substract that
  var res = parseInt(txt1) - parseInt(txt2);
  //Set the value to your div
  document.getElementById("net_worth").value= res;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-9hbo"><br></th>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">Amount ($)<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Other Assets<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty" onblur="fnCalculate()" id="other_assets" type="text" name="other_assets" placeholder="[[+fi.other_assets]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty" onblur="fnCalculate()" id="other_assets_2" type="text" name="other_assets_2" placeholder="[[+fi.other_assets_2]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">(A) TOTAL ASSETS<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input onblur="fnCalculate()" class="totals" id="total_Assets" type="text" name="total_Assets" placeholder="[[+fi.total_Assets]]" readonly /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">(C) NET WORTH (A MINUS B)<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input id="net_worth" type="text" name="net_worth" placeholder="[[+fi.net_worth]]" readonly/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-9hbo"><br></th>
    <th class="tg-9hbo">Amount ($)<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Bank Loans<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty2" onblur="fnCalculate()" id="bank_loans" type="text" name="bank_loans" placeholder="[[+fi.bank_loans]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Mortgages and Real Estate<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="qty2" onblur="fnCalculate()" id="mortgages" type="text" name="mortgages" placeholder="[[+fi.mortgages]]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">(B) TOTAL LIABILITIES<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input onblur="fnCalculate()" class="totals" id="total_liabilities" type="text" name="total_liabilities" placeholder="[[+fi.total_liabilities]]" readonly /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```